# Deploy Hyperledger composer network to AWS or Openstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, openstack, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new to Hyperledger. I have **defined my model** for the network and successfully **deployed it locally**(over my system). **Everything is working as expected**. I want to replicate the same and make it public so that other team members can use it too.

How can I **deploy** the same over cloud hosting services like **AWS or OpenStack**?

I just want that the blockchain services should be available publicly.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud offers a way to do this if you have an IBM Cloud account.

If you do not have and do not want an account, then you could at least look at the scripts being used for deploying to Kubernetes.

[IBM Cloud Sandbox](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/)

The scripts themselves can be downloaded/cloned with this command: `git clone https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-container-service`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't want to use bluemix environment and couldn't find any scripts which could point me towards deploying to kubernetes. Could be great if you can point me to scripts if you have any references.

Comment: I followed the instructions provided in the https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/ (specified in readme file). I got an error: Not authorised to create a cluster on executing the command (bx cs cluster-create --name blockchain). It was giving an option to add a credit card to use this feature. The document claims that it gonna create a free cluster but, if so it shouldn't have asked for a credit card.  I just want to make my network public for integrating UI code.